# Cannot setup apache axis 2 with eclipse helios

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, apache-axis

Im trying to setup Apache Axis2 web services in eclipse, but im getting the following errors in my console. I followed [this](http://blog.sencide.com/2011/06/create-web-service-using-apache-axis2.html) blog to setup a simple web service. But I seem to be missing something. I'm using windows 7 64bit.

```
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL     Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Users\intern\AppData\Roaming\npm\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-    packages\django\bin;D:\shortcuts;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\mongodb\bin;D:\shortcuts\ffmpg;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin;;.
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:myFirstWebService' did not find a matching property.
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyWebService' did not find a matching property.
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:34 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 639 ms
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
[WARN] Web application uses org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet; please update web.xml to use org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet instead
[INFO] Clustering has been disabled
[INFO] Deploying module: addressing-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/intern/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebService/WEB-INF/modules/addressing-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/intern/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebService/WEB-INF/modules/mex-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/intern/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebService/WEB-INF/modules/mtompolicy-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: ping-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/intern/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebService/WEB-INF/modules/ping-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: script-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/intern/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebService/WEB-INF/modules/scripting-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/intern/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebService/WEB-INF/modules/soapmonitor-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying Web service: version.aar - file:/C:/Users/intern/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebService/WEB-INF/services/version.aar
[INFO] Deploying Web service: WebService - file:/C:/Users/intern/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebService/WEB-INF/services/WebService/
[WARN] No transportReceiver for org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener found. An instance for HTTP will be configured automatically. Please update your axis2.xml     file!
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:35 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:35 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:35 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1706 ms
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:406)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:628)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Jan 07, 2013 2:57:35 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:36 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/MyWebService] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.axiom.util.UIDGenerator$1] (value [org.apache.axiom.util.UIDGenerator$1@29fbe6f8    ]) and a value of type [long[]] (value [[J@58f8b950]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 07, 2013 2:57:37 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem. My Tomcat was running as a windows service and it was blocking the localhost port number at 8080. I had to disable the service and ran in eclipse it worked great :)